# Single Signer on Multiple Documents on Single Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the most current DocuSign.eSign.dll NuGet package for C#/.NET.

I have a single Signer, who needs to sign two different documents (PDFs).  I want the signer to sign both the documents together, in the same session.

So, I created a new envelope that has TWO documents (base 64 encoded) and EACH of those documents has the same SINGLE signer, but get back an error saying that the envelope has DUPLICATE RECIPIENTS.

How else am I supposed to construct this API call/envelope, in order for the signer to sign both the documents together, in the same session on the DocuSign website?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code and/or a trace of the JSON request that's being sent to DocuSign when your code runs?  Hard to say where you're going wrong without first seeing your code and/or the JSON request it's generating.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it doesn't give me much to go on. What I'm interested in seeing is how you're constructing "envelope".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your envelope should have one recipient (signer) and two documents.

The `documents` field in the [`envelopeDefinition` object](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) takes an *array* of `document` objects.

Create one document object for each of your documents and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you. I must've understood the structure wrong, and had something goofy going on.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by, Lary K, it needs to be an array. I just posted an example here: [How to send multiple documents for signature DocuSign for Salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272640/how-to-send-multiple-documents-for-signature-docusign-for-salesforce/39341781#39341781)