# How to send multiple documents for signature DocuSign for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

Please can someone assist me. I am new to DocuSign. I have a project I am working on whereby the customer wants to be able to send multiple documents to a recipient for signature. From the standard DocuSign set up, you can add documents upon envelope creation but I am looking for a way to automate this. For instance I created a custom button that automatically sends the envelope to a recepient. But it seems I can only add one document template there. Could someone please advise me on what to actually do or where to look because I cant seem to find anything. I see some recipies on the DocuSign help but they are in python etc and I want instruction on Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[accountId]/envelopes
```

In your create envelope body, you can specify multiple documents like:

`emailSubject: "subject",
recipients: {
  signers: [{
    recipientId: 1,
    email: "signer@email.com",
    name: "Signers name"
}]},
documents: [{
  documentId: 1,
  filePath: 'your/path/here/1',
},
{
  documentId: 2,
  filePath: 'your/path/here/2',
}],`

Comment: thank  you for the post. I currently am doing this via soap and for salesforce integration...any input?